# Function runs successfully once then fails continously

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm not sure why my function only runs once fine. Basically in my JSON, GhStatus and CsStatus both have values of 0 so I am expecting an alert to go off twice saying "crash".

However, this set of alerts only occur once. Then according to Chrome Developer tools, I get errors every 2 seconds saying:

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

However, the output doesn't point out where in the code this occurs =[

```
    $(document).ready(GrabGhCsStatus());

    function GrabGhCsStatus() {
    var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("index","GhCs"))';
    window.setInterval(
        $.get(url,function(data) {
            if (data.GhStatus == 0) {                                                  
                $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });            
                alert('crash');
            }
            else {
                $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });         
                alert('running');
            }
            if (data.CsStatus == 0) {                                                 
                $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });     
                alert('crash');
            }
            else {
                $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });     
                alert('running');
            }
        }, "json"), 2000);                                                  

   }
```

Is the way I formatted this code or where I put the function affecting the output?

Comment: In addition to the below answers, it would be safer to use setTimeout rather than setInterval.

Comment: I jsut read the documentation for setTimeout and I think it says that that function creates an added delay. I'm trying to rerun the code every 2 seconds in order to compare make sure my JSON data has not been changed

Comment: Right, but if you do it with setInterval and the request takes longer than 2 seconds (which isn't uncommon, network issues happen all the time), it could potentially crash the browser over time. using a setTimeout can accomplish the same goal without that possibility because it won't send the next request until the previous one completes.

Comment: hmm i see your logic. Let me try this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax errors, add some more functions and close them properly :

```
$(document).ready(function() { // needs anonymous function
    GrabGhCsStatus();
});

function GrabGhCsStatus() {
    var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("index","GhCs"))';
    $.get(url, function (data) {
        if (data.GhStatus === 0 || data.CsStatus === 0) {
            $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({
                icon: 'myapp-cs'
            });
        }else{
            $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({
                icon: 'myapp-gh'
            });
        }
        setTimeout(GrabGhCsStatus, 2000);
    }, "json");
}
```

Comment: @johusman - indeed, referencing the function works, but in this case the OP hasn't grasped the basics of anonymous functions, and should use the standard ready handler.

Comment: This seems to be the complete answer, +1

Comment: But thank you for discussing the requirement of anonymous function! much appreciated!

Comment: @KevinB thank you for your helpful advice regarding setTimeout! Better safe than sorry! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

the first argument of setInterval needs to be a function.

```
 window.setInterval( function() {

    $.get(url,function(data) {
        if (data.GhStatus == 0) {                                                  
            $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });            
            alert('crash');
        }
        else {
            $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });         
            alert('running');
        }
        if (data.CsStatus == 0) {                                                 
            $('#GhCsStatus_CS').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-cs' });     
            alert('crash');
        }
        else {
            $('#GhCsStatus_GH').buttonMarkup({ icon: 'myapp-gh' });     
            alert('running');
        }
    }, "json") }, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah, you want to enclose the $.get call into a function and pass that function to setInterval:

```
window.setInterval( function() {
    $.get....
}, 2000 );
```

setInterval expects a function as first parameter.
In your case teh return value of $.get() is being passed into setInterval.
And thats probably undefined.